# Multi-NIC Linux VM (ubuntu 16.04 LTS) in Azure and default gateway route

Tags: azure, nic, azure-networking

Can some one please share steps on how to add default gateway address route permanently to the route table on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Azure for the secondary nic?

As you know Azure DHCP only populate the default gateway address for the primary nic.

so basically, in my route table I want to have eth0 --> default gateway address pointing to the subnet gateway address (xx.1) that it is attached to (this is all fine since it's handled by the azure because it's a primary nic) and for the secondary nic i.e. eth1 --> i have to add a manual default gateway address for the subnet that this nic is attached. *hoping this is clear and makes sense*

Here is the document that I'm referring that provides the background.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics#configure-guest-os-for-multiple-nics

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

https://my.esecuredata.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/2/add-a-static-route-on-centos

```
ip route add ???.16.5.0/24 via ??.0.0.101 dev eth?
```

You MUST make sure that the IP address is the start of the CIDR address range you have been allocated, otherwise it will fail.

http://jodies.de/ipcalc

will help you find the CIDR start, of you only have one IP address and mask to go by.

Comment: thanks @birdwes. I know the default gateway address (it's the first address that Azure reserved from the subnet. I'm looking for instructions for ubuntu distro running in Azure. Afaik, centos is a different distro.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but you cannot have multiple default gw.  You specicify the extra ones by subnet xx.xx.xx.xx/yy .

Comment: no need to be sorry. I understand but things are little different in the azure. If you look at the article I sent to you, it discuss this and here is the output that I like to do; Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an UDR in Azure and attach that to the network interface of the VM.

You might also need to configure an persitent route using ip route on your VM. But that's hard to say because we don't know your current routing table, and that might be not supported in Azure, going to do research on that.